# Firebase Cloud Functions - Error with sendToTopic() format

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

My app is a team management system and I want to notify all the players of a certain team if a new event is create via a push notification. There are two types of events that can be created, a `Fixture` and a `Training`. I want to have separate notifications for each of them. I am trying to use `Firebase Cloud Functions` but I keep getting the same error. It says that that the event is triggered but the this error appears. I am quite new to `JavaScript` so please excuse it if it is a simple syntax error but I can't seem to get it to work.

Index.js

```
//import firebase functions modules
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//import admin module
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// // Listens for new fixtures being created
exports.newFixture = functions.database.ref('/Fixture/{currentTeam}/{pushId}').onWrite((change, context) => {

    console.log('new fixture event triggered');

    //  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var valueObject = change.after.val();

  // Create a notification
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "New" + valueObject.type,
            body: "Details:" + " "+ valueObject.date + " " +valueObject.time + " " + "please open app and confirm availability",
            sound: "default"
        },
    };

  //Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("/topics/{currentTeam}", payload, options);
});


// Listens for new trainings being created
exports.newTraining = functions.database.ref('/Training/{currentTeam}/{pushId}').onWrite((change, context) => {

  console.log('New training event triggered');

  //  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  var valueObject = change.after.val();

// Create a notification
  const payload = {
      notification: {
          title: "New" + valueObject.type,
          body: "Details:" + " "+ valueObject.date + " " + valueObject.time + " " + "please open app and confirm availability",
          sound: "default"
      },
  };

//Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority
  const options = {
      priority: "high",
      timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
  };

  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("/topics/{currentTeam}", payload, options);
});
```

Here is the Error

```
Error: Topic provided to sendToTopic() must be a string which matches the format "/topics/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]+".
    at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:241:16)
    at Messaging.validateTopic (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:925:19)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:611:19
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

DB Structure

[image: Training Structure]

[image: Fixture Structure]

Functions Log

[image: FireBase Function LOG]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is:

```
Topic provided to sendToTopic() must be a string which matches the format "/topics/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]+".
```

Your call to sendToTopic() is this:

```
sendToTopic("/topics/{currentTeam}", payload, options)
```

Your use of curly braces is violating the rule stated in the error message.

If you meant to build a topic string with the value of `currentTeam` from the wildcard in your function path definition, you'll need to pull it out of the event context:

```
const currentTeam = context.params.currentTeam
sendToTopic("/topics/" + currentTeam, payload, options)
```